# Permalinks vs pretty URLs

Tags: seo, semantic-markup

Let's say i have a simple blog engine. I've posted a simple post with URL

http://example.org/blog/awesomr-post

Few days later i've noticed the typo and fix my URL

http://example.org/blog/awesome-post

But search engines have already indexed "awesomr-post" and if somebody follow this link he'll get 404 error. There is the same issue with bookmarked pages.

So i think the post should be accepted by two links

http://example.org/blog/awesome-post

http://example.org/permalinks/1

Now i have to specify relationships somehow. What i can do

**http://example.org/permalinks/1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.org/blog/awesome-post">
</head>
<body>
  page content
</body>
</html>
```

**http://example.org/blog/awesome-post**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="bookmark" href="http://example.org/permalinks/1">
</head>
<body>
  page content
</body>
</html>
```

Is it right solution? And should i use the canonical or permalink URL when linking from another site pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way is to have 301 (permanent) redirect from http://example.org/blog/awesomr-post to http://example.org/blog/awesome-post

Comment: It seems like rather ugly solution like for me. Because i have to remember all this temporary links in my database.

Comment: True. But users can get the urls from the browser and it will still say the old url.

Comment: you don't have to remember anything...database does, but that's its job yo. let it do its job

Comment: @albert i think he/she supposed to say 'store' not 'remember' :)

Comment: Ultimately this seems like the most right solution. Thanks.
P.S. The only question is what <link rel> for if you still have to use 301 code?

Comment: @Ximik link rel canonical is only used to tell search engine that those pages are the same, otherwise they will think they are different pages with duplicated content eg www.yoursite.com/ and www.yoursite.com/?any=123

Comment: @ysrb But it seems like 301 makes the same and makes it better.